# NOT LIKE in EF core (expression tree)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm building queries dynamically and i'm having an issue implementing `NOT LIKE`.
My `LIKE` looks like so:

```cs
case "LIKE":
{
    var memberTypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(member.Type);
    var constant = Expression.Constant(value == null ? null : memberTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(value.ToString()!), member.Type);

    body = Expression.Call(
        typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions),
        nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like),
        Type.EmptyTypes,
        Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Functions)),
        member,
        constant
    );
    break;
}
```

This works, but there is no `DbFunctionsExtensions.NotLike` or something along those lines, and i'm not sure how to negate the `Like`.

I tried using something like `IsFalse` but that did not work.

```cs
body = Expression.IsFalse(Expression.Call(
                        typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions),
                        nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like),
                        Type.EmptyTypes,
                        Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Functions)),
                        member,
                        constant
                        )`
...
```

How can I get an expression that evaluates to a `NOT LIKE` query?
How could I write `NOT LIKE` on a normal `Queryable`?

Comment: Don't you just need to wrap it in a `Expression.Not`? So identical to the first but `body = Expression.Not(body)`

Comment: @DavidG let me try that - 1s.

Comment: One thing I find helpful is defining a sample `Expression<Func<>>` in LINQPad and the using the LINQPad `Dump` method to see the compiler generated `Expression` tree. Something like `Expression<Func<Accounts, bool>> f = (Accounts a) => !EF.Functions.Like(a.Application, "%test%");
f.Dump();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to wrap the expression in an [`Expression.Not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.not?view=net-6.0) to reverse the logic. So it could be this:

```
...

body = Expression.Call(
    typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions),
    nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like),
    Type.EmptyTypes,
    Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Functions)),
    member,
    constant
);

body = Expression.Not(body); // <--- Add this
```

Answer (score 0):

Like DavidG pointed out in the comments, the solution is simply `Expression.Not`

```cs
body = Expression.Not(Expression.Call(
        typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions),
        nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like),
        Type.EmptyTypes,
        Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Functions)),
        member,
        constant
    )
);
```

It gives the right query, although with some weird parenthesis.

```sql
WHERE NOT ([l].[ErrorMessage] LIKE N'Duplicate file: ')
```

Comment: You should let the person who gave you the answer make the post :/

Comment: @DavidG ill accept yours in a moment (4min) - why did you post a comment rather than an answer though?

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure it would work, so posting an answer isn't a good idea.

Comment: @DavidG okay - that caught me off guard hence i made the post.